# Как активировать php-gd в Centos?

Tags: php, centos, php7

у меня стоят php70-php-fpm и php73-php-fpm. Установил php-gd

```
Package php73-php-gd-7.3.33-8.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Но в phpinfo() это не отображается. Что нужно сделать, чтобы активировать расширение?

Comment: А можно глупый вопрос — та программа, которая запускает php (например веб-сервер), перезапускалась после установки php-gd?

Comment: Да. Полностью сервер перезапускался. в gd_info() показывается информация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. А какая версия PHP откликается по phpinfo()? 7.0 или 7.3?
2. Где-то у вас должен быть каталог с расширениями (где-то, так как у вас две версии, не решусь ванговать). Примерно php.d должен называться и содержать разные ini-файлы вида

> ```
> 10-opcache.ini
> 20-bcmath.ini
> ...
> 20-gd.ini
> ```

Содержимое 20-gd.ini:

```
; Enable gd extension module
extension=gd
```

3. Посмотрите из консоли у себя, кто откликается как php-fpm и какие ini и откуда подключает:

   $ php-fpm -i | less

   phpinfo() PHP Version => 8.1.9

   System => Linux ...

   Build Date => ...

   Build System => ...

   Build Provider => Remi's RPM repository https://rpms.remirepo.net/

   ...

   Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc

   Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini

   Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d

   Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini,

   ...

   /etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,

   ...